# How to get following text name using xpath?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I try with following xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ReactTags__selected')]//span[1]/text()"));
```

but get following error

> "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[contains(@class,'ReactTags__selected')]//span[2]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element."

```
<div class="ReactTags__selected">
        <span class="tag-wrapper ReactTags__tag" style="opacity: 1; cursor: auto;" draggable="true">
        "TestName"
        <a class="ReactTags__remove">×</a>
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below Xpath.

Hope it helps

```
//div[contains(@class,'ReactTags__selected')]//span[2]/a/text()
```

Comment: There aren't two `<span>` tags in the html ant `text()` is not supported by Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

`text()` in the xpath returns text node, Selenium doesn't support it. Locate the element and use `getText()` to get the text

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ReactTags__selected')]//span[1]"));
String text = element.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the parent element contains the attribute `draggable="true"` invariably it's a dynamic element, precisely [React](https://reactjs.org/) element. Additionally as the text **TestName** is a *Text Node* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the  `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.ReactTags__selected > span.tag-wrapper.ReactTags__tag")))).toString());
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ReactTags__selected']/span[@class='tag-wrapper ReactTags__tag']")))));
  ```